# How do I get an Kodak ESP C315 scanner working?

Tags: scanner, kodak

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32bit. It's working great, but I can't get my scanner to work.

I tried to 'just scan' with simple-scan, but I got the following error:

```
error: no scanner detected, please check your scanner is connected an powered on
```

But the Scanner *is* powered on.

I used a scanner via USB.

Answer (score 2):

My kodak ESP C315 has a card reader slot (MS, SD/HC MMC). The only way I've been able to use the scanner is to scan to a memory card and then stick the sd card into my pc.

There are some untested drivers [here](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html) but I got an error message when installing.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a workaround that is relevant to you. I have a Kodak ESP 9250, and I was able to get it running as a printer under 11.04 (since upgraded to 12.04). I had the same error as you did when I tried to scan directly to the "USB Connected Computer" option.

However, I decided to try scanning to a USB drive plugged into the front of the printer - that worked, and since I had the printer hooked up to my laptop, and the cable was still connected, the USB drive was simultaneously mounted on my laptop!

So if you do a scan to "USB Flash drive", the drive is mounted under `/media`, and your files are in  `/media/(flashdrive ID)/DCIM/(printer ID)/`.

This is not much better than just scanning to the flash drive directly and moving it, but hopefully this helps.